# Django 3.1.4: Get checkbox values in a function in views.py

Tags: django, checkbox, django-views

I don't want to store checkbox values in a database. I just want to get it in a function in views.py
I was not able to find how to do it.

I can already use forms and process the values. But I've to allow user to select options thanks to checkboxes. These checkbox values will be the parameters to run a big script for content based image retrieval. Here is my actual code:

views.py:

```
def form(request):

    val1 = int(request.GET['num1'])
    val2 = int(request.GET['num2'])
    res = val1 + val2

    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', {'result':res})

def essai(request):

    res = request.GET['checks []']

    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', {'result':res})
```

index.html:

```
<form action="add">
    Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="essai">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks []" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks []" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks []" value="3" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please share code of what you did and what is not working

Comment: you can use forms to submit values and then process them.

Comment: please add what you have done till now in question

Comment: @Chandan, Done!
Sorry It's first time I post a question on Stack overflow :)

Comment: can you also add html template - no problem, thank you

Comment: remove space in input name it should be something like this `checks[]` and you can access all values using `request.GET.getlist('checks[]')`.

Comment: @Chandan It solves my problem! I really thank you for your help :D Have a good evening!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="essai">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="3" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```py
def essai(request):

    res = request.GET.getlist['checks[]']

    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', {'result':res})
```

**Note:** if you are sending private or secret information like password, credit card info then it is good to use `POST` method instead of `GET` method in form.

```html
<form action="essai" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="3" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```py
def essai(request):

    res = request.POST.getlist['checks[]']

    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', {'result':res})
```